# python strings remove 1 tab in string

Tags: python, string

I have a string as

```
 "This is a small \t\t world"
```

Assume that the string has 2 tabs in between the words "small" and "world". How can I trim one of the tab spaces so that I get:

```
 "This is a small \t world"
```

The words "small" and "world" can appear only once in the sentence. Basically given two specific words, I want to trim the extra tab between them

Comment: How do you want to identify that? Does it have to be between the words 'small' and 'world'? At the end of the string? This is ambiguous.

Comment: Please check my edit. I want to remove the tab only between the words small and world. I do not want any other tabs to be replaced

Comment: Please clarify what defines the tab that matters, what about the string `"small \t\t world small \t\t world"`? What about `"small foo \t\t bar world"`?

Comment: Yes it has to be between the specified 2 words small and world

Comment: What if those words appear multiple times? What if there is other stuff in between too? What if they are in a different order? It's hard to answer a question like this with such a vague specification of the problem.

Comment: I have a nagging suspicion that you have tried to simplify what you're actually doing. Are there any other variables? For example, could there be anything between `small` and `world` besides one space character on each side and any number of tabs?

Comment: The words "small" and "world" can appear only once in the sentence. Basically given two specific words, I want to trim the extra tab between them without editing any other tabs present in the sentence

Answer (score 2):

Using `re`...

```
import re

s = b"This is        a small         world"

s = re.sub(r'(.*\bsmall *)\t+( *world\b.*)', r'\1\t\2', s)

print s
```

Output:

```
>>> 
This is          a small     world
```

This will keep all spaces before and after the two `tabs`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def remove_tab(st, word1, word2):
    index1 = st.find(word1)
    index2 = st[index1:].find(word2)
    replacement = st[index1:index2].replace('\t\t', '\t')
    return st[:index1] + replacement + st[index2:]
```

Answer (score 1):

using `regex`:

```
In [114]: def func(st,*words):
    rep=" \t ".join(words)
    reg="\b%s\s?\t{1,}\s?%s\b"%(words[0],words[1])
    return re.sub(reg,rep,st)
   .....: 

In [118]: strs='This is \t\t\t a small\t\t\tworld, very small world?'

In [119]: func(strs,"small","world")
Out[119]: 'This is \t\t\t a small \t world, very small world?'

In [120]: func(strs,"is","a")
Out[120]: 'This is \t a small\t\t\tworld, very small world?'
```

Comment: Maybe throw a `\b` in there?  `"small \t\t worldly case"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python re module to use regular expressions:

```
import re

s = "This is \t\t a small \t\t world"

s1 = re.sub(r'(?<=small +)\t+(?= +world)', '\t', s)
```

This will find one or more of `\t` in a row between `"small "` and `" world"` and replace the entire sequence of `\t`'s with a single `\t`.

Comment: I think you should probably make it handle extra whitespace between the small & world

Comment: I edited the code sample to account for one or more spaces characters next to small and world.

Comment: `look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`